# SSH "Login monitor" for Linux

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm trying to write a script that informs the user when someone has logged in on the machine via ssh.

My current idea is to parse the output of "w" using grep in intervals.

But that's neither elegant nor performant. Has anyone got a better idea how to implement such a program?

Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Ubuntu (and I'd guess all other Debian distros, if not all Linuces), the file /var/log/auth.log records successful (and unsuccessful) login attempts:

```
sshd[XXX]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user XXX
```

You could set up a very simple monitor using this command (note that you have to be root to see the auth log):

```
sudo tail -F /var/log/auth.log | grep sshd
```

Comment: Or you could just use "tail -F".

Comment: I've known unix admins who do just about this same thing, for detecting logins as root to their boxen.  If anyone logs in as root, an e-mail is sent to their pager.  Very useful, but occasionally amusing as every time they got into serious maintenance and opened a root shell, they'd get a page...

Answer (score 13):

Paul Tomblin has the right suggestion.

Set up logging in your sshd_config to point to a syslog facility that you can log separately:

=> see man 3 syslog for more facilities. Choose one like e.g.

```
# Logging
SyslogFacility local5
LogLevel INFO
```

Then set up your syslog.conf like this:

```
local5.info    |/var/run/mysshwatcher.pipe
```

Add the script you're going to write to /etc/inittab so it keeps running:

```
sw0:2345:respawn:/usr/local/bin/mysshwatcher.sh
```

then write your script:

```
#!/bin/sh

P=/var/run/mysshwatcher.pipe
test -p $P || mkfifo $P

while read x <$P; do
  # ... whatever, e.g.:
  echo "ssh info: $x" | wall
done;
```

Finally, restart your syslogd and get your inittab reloaded (init q) and it should work. If other variantes of these services are used, you need to configure things accordingly (e.g. newsyslogd => /etc/newsyslog.conf; Ubuntu: /etc/event.d isntead of inittab)

This is very rudimentary and lacking, but should be enough to get you started ...

more info: man sshd_config for more logging options/verbosity.

Comment: Yes, this is almost exactly what I did at my last job, except I used perl to watch the pipe.  I would have posted more details except my source code is at home.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not care how they logged in (telnet/ssh), the 'last' Unix command line utility shows you the last few logins in the machine. Remote users will show the IP address

[root@ex02 www]# last
foo   pts/1        81.31.x.y    Sun Jan 18 07:25   still logged in
foo   pts/0        81.31.x.y    Sun Jan 18 01:51   still logged in
foo   pts/0        81.31.x.y    Sat Jan 17 03:51 - 07:52  (04:00)
bar     pts/5        199.146.x.y  Fri Jan 16 08:57 - 13:29  (04:32

Answer (score 4):

Set up a named pipe, and set up a log file parser to listen to it, and send the ssh messages to it.  The log file parser can do what you want, or signal to a daemon to do it.

Redirecting the log file is done in a config file in /etc/ whose name escapes me right now.  /etc/syslog.conf, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I have made a program (which i call Authentication Monitor) that solves the task described in the question.

If you wanted to, you are more than welcome to download it to investigate how I solve this problem (using log-files).

You can find Authentication Monitor freely available here: http://bwyan.dk/?p=1744

Comment: Please note that bare links to your own website/product are not encouraged here for two reasons; First, an answer should be posted as a self-contained answer, not a mere link to an external site. Second, self-promotion tends to be frowned upon here, and often is flagged as spam (especially if there is no disclosure that you are linking to your own site/product).

Comment: Andrew, cut the guy a break, it is an open source project.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, so we wrote our own script.
It can be downloaded from the [github](https://github.com/IntellexApps/ssh_notify).

Hope it helps :)

cheers!
Ivan

Comment: This is one beautiful bash script.

Comment: @bobef Thx, you made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out SSHLog: https://github.com/sshlog/agent/

It's a daemon that monitors SSH logins as well as user activity. You can push logins and login attempts to syslog, Slack, or statsd.  It also has visibility into command usage and user session activity.